# conversion constructor calling function with no argument

Tags: c++

How conversion constructor is getting used in following program

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>

using namespace std;

class Complex
{
private:
    double real;
    double imag;

public:
    // Default constructor
    Complex(double r = 0.0, double i = 0.0) : real(r), imag(i)
    {}

    // magnitude : usual function style
    double mag()
    {
        return getMag();
    }

    // magnitude : conversion operator
    operator double ()
    {
        return getMag();
    }

private:
    // class helper to get magnitude
    double getMag()
    {
        return sqrt(real * real + imag * imag);
    }
};

int main()
{
    // a Complex object
    Complex com(3.0, 4.0);

    // print magnitude
    cout << com.mag() << endl;
    // same can be done like this
    cout << com << endl;
}
```

I am not able to understand that why statement `"cout << com << endl;"`calling funtion mag(). Please help. if I change function `mag()` to `mag (int i)` then also , same output.

Comment: Why do you think that `cout << com << endl;` calls `Complex::mag()`?

Comment: because output is 5 , and i think , it can not call getMag() because getMag is private, although I am not sure..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`mag()` is never called. Your double conversion operator calls `getMag()` which is why it appears that `mag()` is being called.

When you call `cout << com << endl` there is no overloaded `operator <<` for your `Complex` class. This causes the compiler to look for implicit conversions to something `operator <<` supports. Your complex class has overloaded the double conversion operator here:

```
operator double ()
{
    return getMag();
}
```

As you can see the double conversion operator calls `getMag()` and this it why it appears that `mag()` is being called.

Answer (score 1):

The statement

```
cout<<com<<endl;
```

does not call `Complex::mag()`. It is calling the convertion operator `operator double();`

Comment: why its calling double() ?

Comment: type conversion is being done here. Since you haven't overloaded the class for the output stream, it converts the class to a known type, which is double here.

Answer (score 0):

The class  has conversion operator

```
operator double ()
{
    return getMag();
}
```

So if you have an object of type `Complex` named `com` then in statement

```
std::cout << com << std::endl;
```

there will be called the conversion operator that converts object `com` to an object of type double.

If you will declare the operator with specifier `explicit`

```
explicit operator double ()
{
    return getMag();
}
```

then the statement above will not compile.